# passing mulitiple variables in query string

Tags: php, sql

I want to send multiple variables in a query string like this:

```
<a href="deleteProduct.php?id=11?Mid='A'"></a>
```

and then I want to get these on next page like this :

```
$del=$_GET['id'];
$menu=$_GET['Mid'];
```

But it gives me error that `Mid is undefined`. 
I will be grateful if , some help me . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can test with `isset($_GET['Mid'])` before consuming `$_GET['Mid']`... [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: You're query string should look like `?Mid=foo&id&other=true`. Then $_GET['Mid'] will be 'foo', `$_GET['id']` will be `null` and  `$_GET['other']` will be 'true';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an `&` ***between*** the name-value pairs in your link. Nothing else required.

`?` is there only for the first pair, after that all of them come after `&`, for example

```
delete.php?id=1
delete.php?id=1&id2=3
delete.php?id=1&id2=3&this=test
```